# decimal format rounded to 4 decimal point

Tags: java, decimalformat

i have try to convert my double number into decimal. everytime i toast the number that i have rounded, "java.text.decimalformat@0java.text.decimalformat@0" is shown. this is my code. hope you can help me figure out to toast the number i have rounded.

```
gps = new GPSTracker(Test.this);
    double lat = gps.getLatitude();
    DecimalFormat lat2 = new DecimalFormat();
    lat2.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
    lat2.format(lat);


    double lng = gps.getLongitude();
    DecimalFormat lng2 = new DecimalFormat();
    lng2.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
    lng2.format(lng);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abc);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String ItemChosen = extras.getString("s");

    String latIndex = extras.getString("latt");
    double la = Double.parseDouble(latIndex);
   DecimalFormat la2 = new DecimalFormat();
   la2.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
    la2.format(la);


    String lngIndex = extras.getString("lng");
    double ln = Double.parseDouble(lngIndex);
   DecimalFormat ln2 = new DecimalFormat();
  ln2.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
   ln2.format(ln);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ln2 + " " + la2, 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lng2 + " " + lat2, 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not using `DecimalFormat` properly. The idea isn't that you convert the `DecimalFormat` object itself to a string, as you're doing here:

```
ln2 + " " + la2
```

... it's that you call `format` *and use the return value*.

(Currently you're calling `format` but ignoring the return value, which makes it useless.)

So you want:

```
ln2.format(ln) + " " + la2.format(la)
```

You may want more than that, but that's the most fundamental problem in your current code.